# Angular 17 dependencies conflicts

Tags: angular, npm, dependencies, node-modules

i just initialized a new project with Angular 17 and i don't know why i have an error :

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: project-v2@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/core@17.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/core
npm ERR!   @angular/core@"^17.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/core@"17.0.1" from @angular/animations@17.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/animations
npm ERR!   @angular/animations@"^17.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
```

`@angular/core@"17.0.1" from @angular/animations@17.0.1` : I know that there is no 17.0.1 version. But only 17.0.0.

While i'm posting my issue i found the solution :

I installed :
`npm install @angular/animations@17.0.0`
and
`npm install @angular/core@17.0.0`

and finally :

`ng update`

Answer (score 1):

Delete your `package-lock.json` and you `node_modules` and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 1):

check the compatibility of node version before installing node_modules, you can check it here: https://angular.io/guide/versions .
Install the supported version and delete the package.json file and node_modules.